# Both '00'XC in teradata and hive

Tags: hive, hex, teradata

I found the following query in teradata and there is no error when I run it.

```
Trim(Both '00'XC FROM STG_101_104_BORM_NEW.NO_TRN) AS NO_TRN
```

what is the use of Both '00'XC function?
when I run it on hive there is an error, what should be changed when we translate it to hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Trim(Both '00'XC FROM STG_101_104_BORM_NEW.NO_TRN)` will work in Teradata and it removes leading and trailing null hexadecimal characters from the string.
`'00'XC` - is a null character. XC indicates a hexadecimal string literal and 00 is null in hex.
So trim() is trying to remove it but this will work in teradata but not in hive. You need to know the purpose of this function in teradta and then implement accordingly in hive.
I explained how trim() is different in hive and teradata below.

`trim(origstr)` in hive just removes spaces from left and right of a string.
`trim(both/leading/trailing patternstr from origstr))` in Teradata also removes spaces(and other strings) from the string but it needs more arguments. its more powerful because it can remove bytes/hex characters as well etc.
[Teradata-Trim](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/OcAb9i4CG0K%7EKKFRAJybEw)
For example in hive-
`SELECT TRIM('  aabccd  ') FROM t2;` - will result `aabccd`

For example in teradata-
`SELECT TRIM(BOTH FROM '  aabccd  ') FROM t2;` - will result `aabccd`
`SELECT TRIM(LEADING 'a' FROM 'aabccd') FROM t2;` - will result `bccd`

EDIT :
please use to remove leading and trailing 0.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('000ABCA000','0+$',''),"^0+(?!$)",'')
```

`'0+$'` - this will remove trailing 0s.
`^0+(?!$)` - this will remove leading 0s.

Comment: i tried the following query
SELECT DISTINCT(NO_TRN) FROM PRD_EDW_SRI_VR.SRI_101_104_BORM
WHERE NO_TRN IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY NO_TRN and output like ' &x', ' %E', '#4', ');'
I think to remove the leading and trailing 0 values, so to hive it is like using replace?

Comment: @ryan: replace will also remove binary 0 from *within* the string, you need regex_replace (don't know how to code this pattern it in Hive).

Comment: you need to use reg replace. I just edited the answer.

Comment: And you are not trying to remove 0 characters, you want to remove the NUL character \u0000 (so probably want \\u0000 in the patterns instead of just 0). Also, I don't think you need the negative lookahead assertion (?!$) at the end of the second pattern.

Comment: @ryan is asking to remove 0s... so i gave a solution to remove leading and trailing 0s. if its \u0000, i think like you said, we can replace it. `(?!$)` can be rmeoved...